# How to deal with constructors of differing length with the Factory design pattern?

Tags: c++, factory

I want to have a class that creates different sorts of objects based on a string I pass it. From my research, this best describes the Factory design pattern. I am having success implementing it, but I've run into a design issue: I don't know how to create objects with different length constructors.

Let's take for example, an abstract parent class called Pet. From it are 3 children: Fish, Cat, and Dog. They all inherit weight and color from Pet, so that goes in their constructors. But a fish might want a number of fins and a boolean regarding whether it is a saltwater fish. That's a 4 parameter constructor. Cat would like number of legs. That's 3 parameters. The dog might have parameters for legs, breed, and whether he plays well with other dogs, for 5 parameters.

In C++, I understand that there isn't any reflection, so the most common practice seems to be to just declare a map of string to function pointers, where the function pointer points to a function that looks something like this:

```
    template<typename T> Pet* createObject(int weight, std::string color) {return new T(weight, color);}
```

Again, I'm not sure how I would stuff more parameters into the call without affecting the calls of other objects' constructors.

I can think of two workarounds: make new functions to accept different amount of parameters or make default parameters for constructors above a certain size.

Workaround 1 seems kind of excessive depending on how many different parameter sizes I have.

Workaround 2 seems to disregard the entire point of a constructor, as I will be forced to assign data after calling the constructor.

Are there any other better workarounds?

Comment: You could just use an `if else` on your `string` identifier. Alternatively, you could store prototype objects in your map and use a virtual clone function to create your derived object.

Comment: Looks like you need a feature named perfect forwarding.

Comment: @marom from my understanding, perfect forwarding is orthogonal to OP's issue, which is that his function pointers accept a different number of parameters, so he can't store them in a homogeneous structure.

Comment: @TartanLlama `template<typename ...Args>` is exactly the homogeneous structure the OP is asking for and it works. I just don't have time to write an answer at the moment.

Comment: @nwp (among others) don't overlook the first sentence of the question : the caller sends in a *string*. This is way less trivial than just forwarding statically-typed parameters.

Comment: Who's parsing the string into parameters for each constructor? Maybe you could have the constructors take a string directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variadic templates and perfect forwarding.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
Pet* createObject(Args&&... args) {
    return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

However, since any pointer can be converted to its base class, it would probably be better if this function returns `T*`. Moreover, using naked pointers is not wise, as you'll have to delete them manually. It's better to use [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). For these classes there already are similar factory methods: [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) and [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (the latter only in C++14). Or, if your compiler doesn't support C++11, then you can use `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Of course this solution works when you know at compile time what type you'll need to create. If you have to decide it at runtime, then the whole problem has to be considered from a different direction, as if you don't know what type you are going to create, then there is no way you can know what parameters to give them, except for parameters common for all types. In this case what you need is an [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Fortunately, C++ (at least from C++11) provides a way to implement this pattern without creating a hell lot of classes. For example, let's say you have to create instances of some class derived from `Pet`. The actual kind of pet, its size and other attributes are decided somewhere else, while the name of the pet is decided at the time of creation. Then, you'll need a factory like this:

```
typedef std::function<std::shared_ptr<Pet>(const std::string& name)> PetFactory;
```

At some point you decide that you want to create a `Dog` (I leave the meaning of the actual creation parameters to your imagination).

```
PetFactory petFactory =
        [](const std::string& name) {
            return std::make_shared<Dog>(name, 12, "brown", 23.5);
        }
```

When you actually create it, all you need is to call the factory:

```
std::shared_ptr<Pet> pet = petFactory("Pet Name");
```

Comment: This means specifying the created object type at compile time. Usually with a factory pattern you want to specify the created object at runtime. A straightforward variadic approach with runtime specification of the object type typically leads to UB if a mistake is made.

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant solution and doesn't require me to change a ton of my code. Thanks!

Comment: @NirFriedman What sort of mistakes can be made here? Is there a way I can guarantee non-UB?

Comment: @green_meep if you use this code as is, there isn't a way to get UB, because you are specifying things at compile time. But as you said, you will probably have to have a map of strings to function pointers; to do that the function pointers must be type-erased, and when that happens you will see issues. I can discuss this with you more in chat if you like.

Comment: @NirFriedman Of course if you need to decide which class to use at run-time, then you need to defer the parameters to the point of actual creation. Basically you need to create an abstract factory (e.g. `std::function<std::shared_ptr<Pet>()>` which will hold the actual call to `make_shared` with whatever parameters you want, which are decided earliest at the point where you decide what actual type you need.

Comment: @petersohn I'm not really sure how you envision extending your answer to give run time flexibility. If you can add a snippet that gives similar functionality to my answer, I could better respond. To specify parameters at the same time as class type, you'll need to store functions of different signatures in single container, which will mean some intense type erasure and casting.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the runtime example seems a bit like my workaround 2 that I mentioned. That is, run the highest constructor possible, then assign values as needed afterward.

Comment: @green_meep I don't find it a workaround. It's how these things are done most elegantly. The place where you pass each argument depends on where you know the value of that argument: at the point you create the object or where you decide what the factory will create.

Comment: @petersohn You are locking down the other constructor parameters in advance. What the user wants (my impression) is that you pass a function: a) the name of the class to be created, and b) parameters of the constructor for that specific class, and that function creates the appropriate object and returns a base class pointer. This code does not give you that flexibility.

Comment: @NirFriedman The user has the choice which parameters to lock down when creating the factory, and which ones to defer to the actual creation of the object. This pattern is flexible enough in this request. What you cannot do is to defer parameters that are specific to a subclass. But if you wanted to do that, then you are probably doing something wrong from the beginning and you have to rethink your architecture.

Comment: @petersohn That's a pretty bold claim "you are probably doing something wrong". I've had occasions where children all implemented the same interface, but some needed extra parameters in their constructor. The constructor is certainly a place where one might specify arguments that would affect the implementation, so it's quite conceivable that different children -> different implementation -> different arguments. I do think that the ability to pass subclass specific parameters is exactly what the OP asked for, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need (forgive memory leaks and the like)

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

// definition of pet hierarcy
class pet_t
{
public:
    virtual ~pet_t(void) {}
};

class frog_t : public pet_t
{
public:
    frog_t(int) {}
    static frog_t *builder(int n) { return new frog_t(n); }
};

class dog_t : public pet_t
{
public:
    dog_t(const char *, int) {}
    static dog_t *builder(const char *n, int p) { return new dog_t(n, p); }
};
// the per builder function type
typedef pet_t *(*pet_builder_t)(...);
// the map containing per builders: it's indexed by per type name
std::map<std::string, pet_builder_t> registry;
void build_factory(void)
{
    registry["frog"] = reinterpret_cast<pet_builder_t>(&frog_t::builder);
    registry["dog"] = reinterpret_cast<pet_builder_t>(&dog_t::builder);
}
// the actual factory function
template <class ...Ts>
pet_t *factory(std::string name, Ts&&...ts)
{
    pet_builder_t builder = registry[name];
    // assume there is something in the map
    return builder(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    build_factory();
    dog_t  *dog  = dynamic_cast<dog_t  *>(factory(std::string("dog"), std::string("pluto"), 3));
    frog_t *frog = dynamic_cast<frog_t *>(factory(std::string("frog"), 7));
}
```

I feel like there are too many casts but the idea should be a good starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately, calling one of the builder functions through a pointer to the wrong type sent you to UB land.

Answer (score 0):

If when you create an object, you already know its parameters, and that it will be a Fish, you don't need a factory at all: just construct a Fish and you are done.

You can reasonably make use of a factory in case you don't know which object will result out of it, from the caller. For example you give as input of the factory method a string, maybe read from a file: the factory creates and returns the proper object type by parsing the string.

The caller don't know whether it will be a Fish or a Dog: that's the aim of the factory method.

And moreover you make use of a factory when you can extend it by adding more "constructable" objects by inheritance and overriding the virtual creationist method. That doesn't happen in case the methods have different signatures - they are in fact different methods

Answer (score 0):

Well that was fun ! I've resorted to using factory sub-functions which parse the stream for arguments themselves. I've added in a Registrar pattern for simplicity of use, and of course a good dose of TMP.

Here is the abridged code :

```
/* Pet and derived classes omitted */
/*    Registrar pattern omitted    */

struct PetFactory {
    using PetCtr = std::unique_ptr<Pet> (*)(std::istream &);

    static auto make(std::istream &stream) {
        std::string str;
        stream >> str;
        return ctrMap().at(str)(stream);
    }

    using PetCtrMap = std::map<std::string, PetCtr>;
    static PetCtrMap &ctrMap();
};

template <class T, class... Args, std::size_t... Idx>
auto streamCtr_(std::istream &stream, std::index_sequence<Idx...> const &) {

    std::tuple<Args...> args;

    using unpack = int[];
    unpack{0, (void(stream >> std::get<Idx>(args)), 0)...};

    return std::make_unique<T>(std::move(std::get<Idx>(args))...);
}

template <class T, class... Args>
auto streamCtr(std::istream &stream) {
    return std::unique_ptr<Pet>(streamCtr_<T, Args...>(
        stream,
        std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}
    ));
}

int main() {
    PetFactory::make("fish 1 silver 5 true");
    PetFactory::make("cat 4 tabby 9");
    PetFactory::make("dog 17 white husky playful");
}
```

**Output:**

```
I'm a 1kg silver fish with 5 fins, living in salty water.
I'm a 4kg tabby cat with 9 lives.
I'm a 17kg white husky and I'm playful.
```

The full commented code is available [here on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5aa3660047381336). Thanks for the challenge !

Answer (score -1):

There are many approaches to this problem; the one I prefer may not be the most elegant, but it is extremely explicit. Basically, you create a map to `boost::any` pointers, and all constructors now simply take such a map.

```
using MyArgs = unordered_map<string, boost::any>;

class Fish {
  Fish(MyArgs args) {
    int num_fins = boost::any_cast<int>(args.at("num_fins"));
  }
```

Now all of your constructors have the same signature, so your factory can just look this like:

```
unique_ptr<Pet> factory(string animal_name, MyArgs args) {
  auto func = factory_map.at(animal_name);
  return func(args);
}
```

Edit: I should also note that if you make a mistake, that is your MyArgs is missing an argument or has one of the wrong type, an exception will be thrown. So you can get a nice clear error and even handle it, as opposed to getting UB.